# Are times for links in chats supposed to be in a certain time zone?

Tags: support, chat

I posted a link to an ad for Ask Different and saw the time was different in the chat as opposed to the time stamp.

Are link text supposed to be GMT or should they follow the relative time that stamps the conversation?

[image]

I'm in the central time zone - summer daylight when I snapped this picture.

**Am I missing a setting I can set somewhere so I can see all the times in chat in one time zone?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's UTC (which is also what Twitter's API returns). I guess for tweets we could find a way to localize them (in the live view; the transcript always shows UTC for everything). The same would than have to be done for chat message oneboxes etc.

We'll keep that in the back of our heads, but with low priority – I don't think it really matters very much.

Comment: Is there any thought just making all the chat times UTC so things are consistent? The benefit is letting everyone know what time the system keeps ( daily caps roll over, etc...) Can I choose UTC rather than have the current behavior?

Comment: @bmike There is no setting to switch time displays, no. This is one the notable exception where the live chat doesn't display the local timezone, so I wouldn't consider it overly inconsistent. Most people seem to prefer the local timezone, so that isn't likely to change, although I suppose everything could be userscripted to display UTC anyway if you were determined.